# NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs Item Inaccessible

Tags: c#, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a handler for the `CollectionChanged` event of an `ObservableCollection<T>` object, and cannot figure out how to use the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` to retrieve the item contained within the `IList` for the event.

New items added to the collection are in the `NewItems` property, an `IList` object. Intellisense won't let me access `.Item[Index]` (which I should be able to according to the docs) nor can I cast the `NewItems` list to a local variable (according to debug the `NewItems` list is a `System.Collections.ArrayList.ReadOnlyList` which doesn't seem to exist as an accessible class in MSDN.)

What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
private void ThisCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item I = e.NewItems._________;//<<<<<cannot access any property to get the item
        var j = e.NewItems;//System.Collections.ArrayList.ReadOnlyList, see if you can find in the MSDN docs.
        IList I1 = (IList) e.NewItems;//Cast fails.
        IList<Item> = (IList<Item>)e.NewItems.________;//<<<<<<<Can't make this cast without an IList.Item[Index] accessor.
        var i = j[0]; //null
        var ioption = j.Item[0]; //no such accessor
        string s = (string)i; //null
    }
```

This example is keeping things as generic as possible and still fails.

Comment: You should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be impossible to say exactly what you need to do. But in the meantime, let's try to clear up at least some of your misconceptions from the code you posted:

```
private void ThisCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Item I = e.NewItems._________;//<<<<<cannot access any property to get the item
    var j = e.NewItems;//System.Collections.ArrayList.ReadOnlyList, see if you can find in the MSDN docs.
    IList I1 = (IList) e.NewItems;//Cast fails.
    IList<Item> = (IList<Item>)e.NewItems.________;//<<<<<<<Can't make this cast without an IList.Item[Index] accessor.
    var i = j[0]; //null
    var ioption = j.Item[0]; //no such accessor
    string s = (string)i; //null
}
```

1. [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.newitems(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property, with the type [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), a non-generic interface. The two key aspects of this interface as it relates to the `NewItems` property is that you can get the `Count` of items, and you can index the list. Indexing the list returns an `object`; it's up to you to cast that to an appropriate type.
2. `System.Collections.ArrayList.ReadOnlyList` is a private class in the framework. You are not meant to use it directly. It's simply the implementation of `IList` that the `NewItems` property returns. The important thing about this implementation is that it's read-only. `IList` members like `Add()`, `Insert()`, and `Remove()` are not supported. All you can do is get items out. But just as important is that, as far as your code is concerned, the only type that's important is `IList`. You don't get to access members of private types directly; they are usable only through the public interfaces they implement.
3. You are not specific about what you mean by *"Cast fails"*. That it would is implausible, since the `NewItems` property is already of the type `IList`. A cast to `IList` would succeed trivially.
4. It *is* true that you can't cast `IList` to the generic `IList<Item>`. The implementation of `IList` you're dealing with is the private class `System.Collections.ArrayList.ReadOnlyList`, which can't possibly implement the generic `IList<Item>` interface. After all, the `ReadOnlyList` was written by Microsoft and is in the .NET framework. How would they know about your `Item` type?
5. You are not meant to use the `Item` property indexer of an object explicitly. This exists as a hidden member. Instead, you're expected to use the built-in C# syntax where you index off the object itself. I.e. `e.NewItems[0]` or `j[0]`.
6. Once you have assigned a `null` to the variable `i`, no amount of casting is going to change that `null` value into something else. Not `string`, not some other type.

You've tried a lot of different things, most of which make no sense so it's not a surprise they don't work. The closest you've gotten would be the `j[0]` expression. But you can just use `e.NewItems` directly. Your code should look more like this:

```
private void ThisCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Assumes that the elements in your collection are in fact of type "Item"
    Item item = (Item)e.NewItems[0];

    // do something with "item"
}
```

However, it's important to note that you need to first check to see what kind of change has occurred to the collection. The `NewItems` list may be empty, if there aren't actually any new items. An element of the list may be `null`, if the newly set item value was in fact `null`. Whether you can successfully cast a non-null element value to `Item` depends on what `Item` actually is here, and whether your collection would ever actually have an element of that type in it. Likewise your attempts to cast to `string`. If the list doesn't contain elements of type `string`, then casting any non-null element value to `string` isn't going to work.

But these are all issues that are specific to the rest of the code. You haven't provided that, so the best I can do is try to explain in general terms all of the ways you seem to current misunderstand how this event and its supporting types work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, your snippet is perfect. I can see I was thinking of NewItems as a method instead of a list. In the interests of correcting my misunderstanding, why does an ObservableCollection implement IEnumerable (allowing the extension method .ElementAt(index)) yet the args implements IList (Not allowing ElementAt). I think this might be the source of my confusion.

Comment: `INotifyCollectionChanged` isn't generic; it needs to work with any kind of collection, including non-generic scenarios. So the generic `ElementAt<T>(int)` method can't be used there. Note that while you can call `ElementAt<T>(int)` on an `ObservableCollection<T>` instance, there's no need to because you can index an `ObservableCollection<T>` object directly, e.g. `myObservableCollection[17];` to get the element at index 17. You should prefer direct indexing over use of extension methods.